# Azure Data Factory data sink seems to be hidden or collapsed so it can't be validated

Tags: azure-data-factory

[image: Data Flow in Azure Data Factory - two sinks defined but one is collapsed]

I'm quite new to Data Factory, so perhaps this is something very obvious that I'm missing.

I removed one of my datasets from within the list of Factory Resources (the pane on the left) and created a new one so that I could name it correctly. Previously, the dataset I deleted was associated with a data flow sink, which was named crmConstituent - this can be seen at the bottom of my screenshot. I now realise I should have removed the sink before I deleted the dataset, but I got ahead of myself.

I then added a new/replacement sink to my data flow, named SinkConstituents, associated with my recreated dataset. However, it looks like the original sink has persisted in the data flow somewhere and I can't seem to remove it using the interface. To the right of NameColumns in the top row of the flow, I can see my fresh new sink (SinkConstituents) but in between the two, I can also see another blue line that is possibly part of my old sink that I wanted to remove, but it appears to be only partially visible, as though it is collapsed. If I right-click on the "collapsed sink", it comes up with the option to delete it, but this doesn't appear to actually do anything if I select delete; the blue line remains and so does the error. I can't click on the collapsed sink to view the configuration of it in the bottom pane.

I'm currently unable to validate my factory because the original sink named crmConstituent doesn't have a dataset any more (because I am a monster who deletes things without thinking ahead), but I don't seem to be able to remove the sink from my data flow or recreate the original dataset to soothe the sink into thinking nothing is missing after all.

Comment: This looks like a corrupted graph. Not sure how it happened, but you'll need to fix it in the data flow script by editing by hand. Use the script icon on the top right of the designer and remove the sink definitions manually. If you need help, just paste the script in a reply here.

Comment: Thanks very much - I was worried this might be the case. I'll leave my original question here in case anyone else encounters the same issue, but for me, it was easier to discard my changes and redo them more carefully, making sure I did things in the correct order to avoid the issue recurring.